# Do I get a notification from epoll when a fd is closed?

Tags: linux, epoll

I am currently building something that uses `epoll`. It works pretty nice, but it would be good to have a notification when a file descriptor gets removed from `epoll` when the underlying `fd` is closed.

Is there a way to get a notification from `epoll` as soon as an `fd` is closed?

Comment: What do you want to do with such a notification?

Comment: Is that relevant for the question? I wrapped epoll into a C++ class and I have a list that maps an fd to an object. Normally delete should be called to remove a fd, but I want to catch the error on close as well and purge the mapped object of the list...

Comment: If you want to check for errors you can do it manually. Go over the desctiptors and call epoll_ctl(EPOLL_CTL_MOD) on each. If you get an error you know it was closed. But better encapsulate and hide the fd and don't let it be closed on a whim.

Comment: In theory it should not be closed while it is in epoll. But e.g. a socket can be closed remotely

Comment: No, it can be *shut down* remotely, but not closed. It is closed only when you call `close`.

Comment: ah okay, thanks for that differentiation. then I do not have a problem at all :). Thank you!

Comment: Not only you won't get notified, but your premisse is wrong: it may not be removed from epoll when you close. You may keep receiving notifications for a closed socket, and you have no way to know it.

Answer (score 3):

No. Here's a [Zig](https://ziglang.org/) program to demonstrate:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const epollfd = blk: {
        const rc = std.os.linux.epoll_create1(std.os.linux.EPOLL_CLOEXEC);
        const err = std.os.linux.getErrno(rc);
        if (err != 0) return error.EpollCreateFailed;
        break :blk @intCast(i32, rc);
    };
    defer std.os.close(epollfd);

    var pipe: [2]i32 = undefined;
    {
        const rc = std.os.linux.pipe2(&pipe, std.os.linux.O_CLOEXEC);
        const err = std.os.linux.getErrno(rc);
        if (err != 0) return error.PipeCreateFailed;
    }

    var ev: std.os.linux.epoll_event = undefined;

    ev.events = std.os.linux.EPOLLIN | std.os.linux.EPOLLET;
    ev.data.fd = pipe[0];
    {
        const rc = std.os.linux.epoll_ctl(epollfd, std.os.linux.EPOLL_CTL_ADD, pipe[0], &ev);
        const err = std.os.linux.getErrno(rc);
        if (err != 0) return error.EpollCtlFailed;
    }

    const thread = try std.os.spawnThread(pipe[0], threadStart);

    var events: [10]std.os.linux.epoll_event = undefined;
    const nfds = blk: {
        std.debug.warn("epoll wait\n");
        const rc = std.os.linux.epoll_wait(epollfd, &events, @intCast(u32, events.len), -1);
        std.debug.warn("epoll wakeup\n");
        const err = std.os.linux.getErrno(rc);
        if (err != 0) return error.EpollWaitFailed;
        break :blk rc;
    };
    if (nfds != 1) return error.NotExactly1FileDescriptor;
    std.debug.assert(events[0].data.fd == pipe[0]);
    thread.wait();
}

fn threadStart(fd: i32) void {
    std.os.time.sleep(1, 0);
    std.debug.warn("close fd\n");
    std.os.close(fd);
}
```

It outputs:

```
epoll wait
close fd
^C
```

(I had to kill it with Ctrl+C because it never woke up.)

Here's the strace output:

```
execve("./test", ["./test"], 0x7fff311ff208 /* 122 vars */) = 0
epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC)            = 3
pipe2([4, 5], O_CLOEXEC)                = 0
epoll_ctl(3, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 4, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLET, {u32=4, u64=4}}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_GROWSDOWN, -1, 0) = 0x7fd082ed9000
clone(child_stack=0x7fd0836d8fd8, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|0x400000, parent_tidptr=0x7fd0836d8fe4, child_tidptr=0x7fd0836d8fe4) = 13547
strace: Process 13547 attached
[pid 13546] write(2, "epoll wait\n", 11epoll wait
<unfinished ...>
[pid 13547] nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13546] <... write resumed> )       = 11
[pid 13546] epoll_wait(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13547] <... nanosleep resumed> 0x7fd0836d8f20) = 0
[pid 13547] write(2, "close fd\n", 9close fd
)   = 9
[pid 13547] close(4)                    = 0
[pid 13547] exit(0)                     = ?
[pid 13547] +++ exited with 0 +++
^Cstrace: Process 13546 detached
```

Comment: Upvoted because you're to only one who at least understood the question :p.  I did the same test in C++ and found the same results: a close() does not cause a wake up from epoll_wait(). This is almost trivially expected behavior because a common use case is where data.fd is set to the (now closed) fd, or otherwise it is pretty normal that after removal from the interest list whatever data.ptr points to is deleted, so you really don't want an 'event' on that object. However, and that is why I'm interested in this question / answer, there seems to be a race condition: if an event happens

Comment: and epoll_wait() returns - and THEN immediately *another* thread closes that fd - you have the exact same problem as if the close() caused the wake up: either data.fd is now invalid (or even was reused and points to a new device) or data.ptr was deleted (my problem). It seems that the only way to solve this is by adding a new flag for epoll_ctl that allows one to be notified with an event that requests data.ptr to be deleted, possibly initiated by a close(2).

Answer (score -1):

You need to watch out for when `epoll_wait()` returns `-1`, then check the `errno` value to see if it matches `EBADF`.

See `man epoll_wait()`, `man errno` for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to the manpage: `EBADF  epfd is not a valid file descriptor.`. So this only applies for the file descriptor of the epoll object itself, not on the fds that the epoll object contains.

Comment: When the file is closed; the file descriptor will be invalid.

Comment: Closed fds are removed from the epoll set automatically, so there will not be any error.

Comment: exactly. So I guess the only way is to try to add every fd in the list and see if EPOLL_CTL_ADD will give me an EEXISTS errormessage. Which is ugly...

Comment: This post is not an answer to the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

Not.  As soon as the file descriptor is closed, it is no longer available for anything but to be used by the kernel in a new file descriptor.  As soon as you don't get it again as a result of a new `open(2)`, `create(2)`, `socket(2)`, etc. system call, it will be invalid to use it as a parameter for any system call (and this includes `select(2)` and `epoll(2)`)

The kernel has freed the file descriptor entry in your process' structure, so it's not valid to use it.

Sorry, I said:

> The only way you can get something from `epoll(2)` in case you close it is if you have two threads and you `close(2)` the file descriptor in one thread while you are waiting for it in another thread.  This time you'll get immediate return from the `epoll(2)` system call with probably some kind of error (I have not tested this) but I think this is not your scenario.

As I then said, I had not tested it, but now, I can say that in course system calls are not interrupted, but left to finish.  Anyway, the file descriptor is not valid in any thread to be used for a new system call anymore.  The code in the NOTE below shows how this happens.  But the conclusion is that **after `close(2)` you cannot use the file descriptor passed to the system call anymore in the process**, as I said before.  (of course, you can if you get the same file descriptor value as a consequence of a new `open(2)`, `socket(2)`, etc. system call)

## NOTE

just tested with the following code: if you `close(2)` a file descriptor and other threads are blocked in system calls related to that file descriptor, the system calls are not aborted, but the file descriptor is not valid anymore.  On termination of those system calls, the file descriptor is unusable anymore, neither in the thread that `close(2)`d it, nor in the the other threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buffer[100];

void *f(void* arg)
{
    int res;
    printf("f: waiting on read()\n");
    res = read(0, buffer, sizeof buffer);
    printf("f: read %d bytes\n", res);
    if (res < 0) {
            printf("this was an error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    } else {
            printf("f: read: %.*s", res, buffer);
    }
    printf("f: waiting on read()\n");
    res = read(0, buffer, sizeof buffer);
    printf("f: read %d bytes\n", res);
    if (res < 0) {
            printf("f: this was an error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    } else {
            printf("f: read: %.*s", res, buffer);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t;
    int res = pthread_create(&t, NULL, f, NULL);
    printf("main: waiting 10 seconds\n");
    sleep(10);
    printf("main: closing stdin\n");
    close(0);
    printf("main: waiting another 10s.\n");
    sleep(10);
    printf("main: waiting for thread.\n");
    pthread_join(t, NULL);
    printf("main: reading from stdin\n");
    res = read(0, buffer, sizeof buffer);
    printf("main: read %d bytes\n", res);
    if (res < 0) {
            printf("main: this was an error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    } else {
            printf("main: read: %.*s", res, buffer);
    }
    printf("main: exiting.\n");
}
```

This code results in this sequence:

```
$ a.out
main: waiting 10 seconds
f: waiting on read()
main: closing stdin               <--- now the fd is closed
main: waiting another 10s.
lorem ipsum                       <--- input
f: read 12 bytes
f: read: lorem ipsum
f: waiting on read()
f: read -1 bytes                  <--- file descriptor is not valid in the second read(2) call.
f: this was an error: Bad file descriptor
main: waiting for thread.         <--- joining thread f
main: reading from stdin
main: read -1 bytes               <--- invalid also for main thread.
main: this was an error: Bad file descriptor
main: exiting.
```

Comment: downvoting without explanation of why is neither polite nor instructive.  Please, drop a note for the reason of the downvote.  Be positive, even when downvoting :)

Comment: I downvoted it too and well because it is incorrect. If you `close(2)` a fd, that will not cause any `epoll_wait(2)` to return, in any thread. Furthermore, the first part seems unrelated to what the OP asked: whether or not `epoll_wait(2)` can be made to return with a 'closed event' when another thread closes the fd.

Comment: @CarloWood, sorry, but I don't say that it caused to return any in course system call.  I said that _probably (and that I hadn't tested that)_, any active system calls could be interrupted on the `close(2)` (the tty driver actually does, as a result of the invalidate done to it on the last close of the tty, that makes any in course system call to return, but this is different in linux than in unix)  Anyway, I have updated my answer to reflect what actually happens with an example.